# Foreach loop is slow in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, performance, loops, foreach, visual-studio-2012

I’m having a performance issue with the following loop when I migrate up.  It was originally written in VS2003.  This loop takes about 20 seconds to run in VS2003.  In VS2005, VS2008, VS2010 and VS2012 this same loop takes 5 hours to run.  There have been no code changes and all versions are running on the same PC.  Has anybody had performance issues like this before when trying to migrate up in Visual Studio?  I have run this loop in the following Versions of Visual Studio and here are my results in h/mm/ss format.

```
VS2003    VS2005    VS2008     VS2010    VS2012
0:00:20   9:50:15   20:15:02   8:42:08   4:58:09


//dstPrvTbleSeq has 114881 rows
//dstPrvTbl has 104070 rows                                                             


foreach (DataRow dr in drSeq)
{   // in query PrvLocID is selected as PrvID to match with extract requirements
    DataRow[] drSelect = dstPrvTbl.Tables[0].Select("PrvID=" + dr["PrvID"].ToString() + " and TermDate is null");
    if (drSelect.Length > 0)
    {
        dr.Delete();
    }
    else
    {
        //delete duplicate term record with different fee schedule, only the first sequence fee schedule should show up as term
        DataRow[] drSelect2 = dstPrvTbl.Tables[0].Select("PrvID=" + dr["PrvID"].ToString() + " and TermDate is not null");
        if (drSelect2.Length > 0)
        {
            if (dr["TermDate"].ToString() != "")//if a term record for provider location id is already there and a new term record for another plan code comes across then delete the new one from file
                dr.Delete();
            else if (sPrvFileName.Trim().ToUpper() == "NEPTUNE.TXT" || sPrvFileName.Trim().ToUpper() == "PROV.TXT") //if Neptune file then remove the previous old term record and keep the new active record
            {
                drSelect2[0].Delete();//delete the old term record for neptune file
                dstPrvTbl.AcceptChanges();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand... what framework version are you targetting?

Comment: wow. I want to know the end of the story.

Comment: Show the actual timing behind the scenes, surely there must be something wrong. Also the machine specs. Probably, you forgot to stop the stopwatch?

Comment: Thanks nawfal.  I set a textwriter to grab the DateTime.Now right before the loop and right after it.  I have never been able to figure out what the problem was.  I replaced the loop with a linq query.  Now I'm back the 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Definitly your problem is not a matter of the version of Microsoft Visual Studio. Even if it was, there is a huge difference between 20 seconds and 2 HOURS!! and it doesn't make any sense at all. I'd suggest you to check the code, database connection you have, and the data operations using some tools like profiler and find out what the real problem is.

Hope it helps

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There shouldn't be that much difference. Make sure you are not in debug mode. Release mode and not debugging run should be faster than in debugging mode in VS.

Comment: Thanks for closing this problem.  I can't imagine other users having this problem with Visual Studio 2012 in the future.  We all know Microsoft has a stellar reputation for introducing bug-free applications.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is a matter if what version of the IDE you're using. I think it is a matter of which version of the .Net Framework you're targetting. Make sure you target at the VERY least 2.0. 1.1 is completely deprecated by now, and God knows what kind of bizarre bugs you can find in it.

Also, I don't think they checked whether or not Visual Studio 2010 or 2012 were really working ok with such ancient versions of the framework.